# Understanding the Mercurial merge changeset

Tags: mercurial, merge

If I have two heads in my repo - C and D which have the common parent of B - and I do an `hg merge` then a `hg commit`, what exactly is in that merge changeset?  I am trying to understand what I see what I do `hg diff -c xyz` where xyz is the id of the merged changeset.

Will the changeset show the diffs of all files modified in C and D vs. the state of those files as they existed in the common parent repository B?

Comment: Incidentally, if you want to get the changes of two branches merged relative to their common ancestor (e.g. C and D vs B), use `hg diff -r "ancestor(p1(REV), p2(REV))"` where REV is a merge changeset.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A merge commit has two parents, so when running a diff it is important to understand which parent you are diffing against.

`hg diff -c <changeset>` shows the diff of the changeset relative to the first parent.

From [`hg help diff`](http://www.selenic.com/hg/help/diff):

> diff may generate unexpected results
>   for merges, as it will default to
>   comparing against the working
>   directory's first parent changeset if
>   no revisions are specified.

To diff against a specific parent, it is best to provide the explicit revision of both the merge changeset and corrent parent (e.g. `hg diff -r <parent> -r <merge changeset>`

Comment: Thanks.  What is the logic that Mercurial uses to set which head gets set as parent #1 vs parent #2?  It seems like the tip is usually parent #2.  So the diff will be against the older changeset.  Which does make sense to me.

Comment: @Marcus: Merges are directional.  The typical merge workflow is `hg update -r <changeset 1>; hg merge -r <changeset 2>; hg commit -m "merged branch"`.  In this example, "parent 1" is `<changeset 1>` and "parent 2" is `<changeset 2>`.

Answer (score 2):

Mercurial implements a [directed acyclic graph](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Directed_acyclic_graph) so in your merge changeset depends on where you're coming from.  When you type "hg merge" it assumes "tip" (much in the same way hg pull assumes the root repository from which you cloned your head)  If you type "hg heads" you can see which one is the tip. When you do this merge, assuming C as the tip, you are merging in the changes from D.

Comment: I feel like I'm seeing different results.  Say I have A->B->D in my repo, then I do `hg pull` which adds C so now I have B->D and B->C where C is the tip.  Now I do `hg merge`, `hg ci`, `hg diff -c xxx` - I feel like in my diff it listing new files from C as ADDS, deleted files from C as DELETES, and any changes from C as CHANGES.  Logically in the diff C is the "before" and the merged results are the "after".   Is this what you are describing?

Comment: Yes. If you go to the source control (where you cloned from initially) in a web browser, you can click on graph on the side to see a visual representation of this.